# Print given ip printer

Tags: java, ip, ip-address, printers

I want to print a pdf file, given the printer's IP address, the IP address is stored in a table in the database, I read the ip address of that table (which is type string), and that is the ip address of the printer where I want to print.
I tried a thousand ways, but still I can not get what I need.
I'm programming in java language.

In this way, I get a list of ip address:

```
PrintService[] service = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();// list of ip address 
PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
printJob.setPrintService(service[0]);//I get the first address
```

But, I need to set the ip address, which I read from my database, I don't need that list:

I know this is not correct, but this is the idea:

```
service[0] = "\\10.100.17.93\HP LaserJet Professional P1102w";
//I want to assign the ip address
```

Comment: I think that each printer should be installed in the operating system for this to work.

Comment: There is some of code.... help me pleaseeeeeeeee!!!! =/

Answer (score 0):

[Related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655297/print-to-specific-printer-ipp-uri-in-java/1662852#1662852) 
[Jipsi @Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jipsi/)

Haven't used Jipsi myself, though I intend to try it out soon.
From what I understand, you can send printjobs to a networkprinter which is declared on a server. This could be an Active Directory (domain) server in a Microsoft setup, or a Cups server which is on Linux.

Let me know if this works for you.