# Printing PDF to network printer

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to print a PDF on an unmapped network printer in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441063/how-to-print-a-pdf-on-an-unmapped-network-printer-in-java)

I know the printer ip address  , and the printer is in the network. How can I print PDF document in JAVA to that printer . Please send a sample code.

I Really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: I assume you've tried nothing at this point?

Comment: Read this blog - http://bfo.com/blog/2012/02/15/using_java_to_print_pdf_documents.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try PDF Renderer. That will help you print PDF documents.

A source where you can find the PDF-Renderer class:
http://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/com/sun/pdfview/PDFRenderer.java?rev=140

A similar question asked by someone. This one has the code:
[Java PDF Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437910/java-pdf-viewer)

FOR THE CODE:
http://www.idrsolutions.com/how-to-print-pdf-files-in-java/

One final thing. Atleast do some work by yourself. Don't expect this everytime. Show some work, so we know what you are looking for. Don't you read the rules?