# Print a doc on specific printer using JPS( java print service)

Tags: java, printing, ipp-protocol

I want to print a document from a specific printer(standard Alone Program).

Input: IP address, printer name(Using Jdk 1.6)

I have followed the below URL

[Print to specific printer (IPP URI) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655297/print-to-specific-printer-ipp-uri-in-java)

But I did not find ***IppPrintService*** class in jdk1.6.

Could you please help me out, how to implement this using jdk1.6?

Comment: Maybe you didn't find it cause the answerer said its in `jipsi`?

Answer (score 0):

***IppPrintService*** is part of the library [jspi](https://github.com/bhagyas/jspi).

If you just want to submit a printable document like PDF via IPP to a printer (or to CUPS) this code provides a minimalistic implementation without dependencies.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class IppPrintJob {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    URI printerURI = URI.create("http://colorjet:631/ipp/printer");
    File file = new File("A4-blank.pdf");
    short status = new IppPrintJob().printDocument(printerURI, new FileInputStream(file));
    System.out.println(String.format("ipp status: %04X", status));
  }

  void writeAttribute(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, int tag, String name, String value)
  throws IOException
  {
    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    dataOutputStream.writeByte(tag);
    dataOutputStream.writeShort(name.length());
    dataOutputStream.write(name.getBytes(charset));
    dataOutputStream.writeShort(value.length());
    dataOutputStream.write(value.getBytes(charset));
  }

  short printDocument(URI uri, InputStream documentInputStream) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.toURL().openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/ipp");
    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
    dataOutputStream.writeShort(0x0101); // ipp version
    dataOutputStream.writeShort(0x0002); // print job operation
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(0x002A); // request id
    dataOutputStream.writeByte(0x01); // operation group tag
    writeAttribute(dataOutputStream, 0x47, "attributes-charset", "utf-8");
    writeAttribute(dataOutputStream, 0x48, "attributes-natural-language", "en");
    writeAttribute(dataOutputStream, 0x45, "printer-uri", uri.toString());
    dataOutputStream.writeByte(0x03); // end tag
    documentInputStream.transferTo(outputStream);
    dataOutputStream.close();
    if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
      System.out.println(
        String.format("ipp version %d.%s", dataInputStream.readByte(), dataInputStream.readByte())
      );
      return dataInputStream.readShort();
    } else {
      throw new IOException(String.format(
          "post to %s failed with http status %d", uri, httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()
      ));
    }
  }

}
```