# Print a PDF in a local IP printer

Tags: java, android, pdf, printing

You can print a PDF directly to a local IP printer? The printer is not connected to any PC.

I can not use Google Cloud Print as I have no outlet to the Internet.

If I use a SOCKET me prints strange characters, since I have no driver for your printer.

Greetings and thank you very much.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You would have to ask the manufacturer of the printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just open a socket to the printer and start streaming data.  You need to use a library that supports [Internet Printing Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Printing_Protocol).

If the printer is mapped as a printer on the computer from which you'd like to print, you should be able to use the [Java Print Service API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/JPSTOC.fm.html).

If it's not mapped, you'll probably need to use a third party library.  See the top rated answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655297/print-to-specific-printer-ipp-uri-in-java).